# How can I make my back4app app use a custom s3 bucket under my own aws account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parse-server, back4app

I have set the following settings.

Environment variables:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID={my access key name}
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY={my access key}
```

Custom Parse settings:

```
"filesAdapter": {
    "module": "@parse/s3-files-adapter",
    "options": {
        "bucket": {my bucket name},
        "region": "us-west-2"
    }
}
```

In AWS, I've created that bucket, created an IAM user with access to the bucket and the access key that I put into the environment variables.

Not sure why this isn't working. Is there anything else I should be doing? Thanks.

Comment: I saw you tagged back4app. In order to configure a custom S3 adapter in your app, you must check if you are running on an available plan and also contact them, then, they will help you to configure it to your app.